# Override sendSwiftMessage() Laravel Swiftmailer with custom

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**I am using Laravel 4.2**

**The answer given by user3158900 is for Laravel 5.*
Any one can help me with version 4.2 ?**

I would like to override sendSwiftMessage() protected function with my own function.

**sendSwiftMessage()** is located in

> "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php"

I created a

> Lib/Mailer/CustomMailer.php

and Set the folder Lib to autoload in composer (PSR4).
I can now call/load my function in my controllers by writing:

> new Lib\Mailer\CustomMailer;

This is how my file looks like:

```
<?php namespace Lib\Mailer;

class CustomMailer extends \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer {

    /**
     * Send a Swift Message instance.
     *
     * @param  \Swift_Message  $message
     * @return void
     */
    protected function sendSwiftMessage($message)
    {
        if (strpos($message->toString(), 'noemail@noemail.com') == true) {
            Log::info('Not sending mail to noemail@noemail.com');
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->events)
            {
                $this->events->fire('mailer.sending', array($message));
            }

            if ( ! $this->pretending)
            {
                $this->swift->send($message, $this->failedRecipients);
            }
            elseif (isset($this->logger))
            {
                $this->logMessage($message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, this sendSwiftMessage() function is not used when I send an email with Swiftmailer in my controller by doing EXAMPLE:

```
Mail::send(xxxx);
```

**My question:** How can I make Swiftmailer/Laravel use my custom sendSwiftMessage() function when I send a message if I don't want to modify all my Controllers that currently use the Mail::send() code

Comment: The answer from user3158900 is for Laravel 5.*
Any one can help me with version 4.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Think I got this figured out, however I am getting an error but I think that's on you because your custom class is using a property that doesn't exist so here's the solution anyway.

In `AppServiceProvider.php` in the `boot()` method, I've added the following:

```
$this->app->singleton('customMailer', function($app) {
    return new CustomMailer(
        $app['view'], $app['swift.mailer'], $app['events']
    );
});
```

In `app/Lib/Mailer` folder, I've added another class for the facade.

```
namespace App\Lib\Mailer;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Mail extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'customMailer';
    }
}
```

In `config/app.php`, I've replaced the `Mail` alias with the following...

```
'Mail' => App\Lib\Mailer\Mail::class,
```

And that should be all you need to do.

One other thing, I just noticed you are missing in your namespace the `App` which explains why you had to add the `Lib` folder to the autoloader.  If you namespace it correctly to keep it inline with PSR-4 by adding the `App\` onto the beginning, then you don't need to add anything to your `composer.json` file to get additional classes loaded.

Comment: Could you please show me where the AppServiceProvider.php should be located and the beginning of the file, thanks!! I'm trying it right now but still stuck over there

Comment: Oh you are using Laravel 4.  I'm sorry, this code may not work.